# "what" vs "which" in non-defining relative clauses

Tags: relative-clauses

According to [google ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=which%20took%20us%2Cwhat%20took%20us&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cwhich%20took%20us%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwhat%20took%20us%3B%2Cc0) the second variant is more widely used:

1. > [It was cold there], **what took us by surprise**.
2. > [It was cold there], **which took us by surprise**.

Can anybody, please, explain me why? Which variant is better? Will it be a mistake to use the first one?

Comment: In (1) "what took us by surprise" is ungrammatical since "what" is not ordinarily allowed in relative clauses in Standard English. (2) is fine, of course.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 1. It was cold there, **what** took us by surprise.
> 2. It was cold there, **which** took us by surprise.

In both examples, the words in bold refer to *It was cold there* – a clause.

As a relative pronoun, *what*, unlike *which*, cannot be used to refer to a previous clause. Therefore, only sentence 2 is grammatical.